# How to toggle between two picker views in the same class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have taken 2 Arrays to pass data in the respective Picker View. I have passed the Picker Views on `UITextField`. I have 2 text-fields on particular text-field selection the associated picker view should come up. I tried some ways still no result.

Here's the code:

```
 //First Picker View
self.pickerFillStatus = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
self.pickerFillStatus.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.pickerFillStatus.delegate = self;
self.pickerFillStatus.dataSource =self;
self.fillArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Single",@"Married Filling Jointly",@"Married Filling Separately",@"Head of House Hold",nil];
self.txtFillingStatus.inputView = self.pickerFillStatus;
self.txtFillingStatus.tag = 1;

// Second Picker View
self.pickerState = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
self.pickerState.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.pickerState.delegate = self;
self.pickerState.dataSource =self;
self.stateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SC",@"VT",@"OR",@"PA",@"RI",nil];
self.txtState.inputView = self.pickerState;
self.txtState.tag = 2;

  // All the Datasource and Delegates    
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {  
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
  numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
     if (self.txtFillingStatus.tag == 1) {
         return self.fillArray.count;
    } else if (self.txtState.tag == 2) {
        return self.stateArray.count;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
    (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (self.txtFillingStatus.tag == 1) {
         [_txtFillingStatus setText:[self.fillArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    }else if (self.txtState.tag == 2) {
        [_txtState setText:[self.stateArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:
   (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (self.txtFillingStatus.tag == 1) {
        return [self.fillArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }else if (self.txtState.tag == 2) {
        return [self.stateArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: show your textFieldDidBeginEditing: method

Comment: i dint add that method @ismail

Comment: -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField add this method. and in this method you can set the condition using tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is there is no need to create 2 picker views. Your functionality can be achieved by only one picker view itself. What you need to do is

1.Create a picker view. For example

```
- (void) createPickerView {
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [pickerView setDelegate:self];
    [pickerView setDataSource:self];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

2. In your textFieldDidBeginEditing method reload the pickerView components based upon the textfield selected.Look at the code below for reference. Here "currentTextfieldForPicker" is a  NSString *currentTextfieldForPicker; . "TXTFILLING_STATUS" and "TXT_STATE" are two strings to identify which textfield is clicked.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

          if (textField == txtFillingStatus) {
    currentTextfieldForPicker = TXTFILLING_STATUS;

    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];

    }

    else if (textField == txtState) {

    currentTextfieldForPicker = TXT_STATE;

    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];

    }

    }

3.     Now implement picker view delegates as follows:
    // Total rows in our component

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerViewnumberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if ([currentTextfieldForPicker isEqualToString:TXTFILLING_STATUS]) {
        return [fillArray count];
    }else if ([currentTextfieldForPicker isEqualToString:TXT_STATE]) {
        return [stateArray count];
    }
    else  {
        // Some default array if you want to
        return [inputDataArray count];
    }
}
    // Display each row's data.
    -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        if ([currentTextfieldForPicker isEqualToString:TXTFILLING_STATUS]) {
            return [fillArray objectAtIndex:row] ;
        } else if ([currentTextfieldForPicker isEqualToString:TXT_STATE]) {
            return [stateArray objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        return [inputDataArray objectAtIndex:row] ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing reference to you `self.txtFillingStatus.tag`in the if.
Try it doing reference to the picker class.

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

  if ([pickerView isEqual:self.pickerFillStatus]) {

    return self.fillArray.count;

  } else if (([pickerView isEqual:self.pickerState]) {
    return self.stateArray.count;
  }

 return 0;
}
```